# How to follow specific links and scrape content using scrapy?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, scrapy

Say I have one main page, `index.html` and four child pages, `1.html … 4.html`. All pages are linked on the main page, in the same way.

How can I follow these specific links with Python's `scrapy` and scrape content following a repetitive pattern.

Here is the setup:

*index.html*

```
<body>
<div class="one"><p>Text</p><a href="1.html">Link 1</a></div>
…
<div class="one"><p>Text</p><a href="4.html">Link 4</a></div>
</body>
```

*1.html…4.html*

```
<body>
<div class="one"><p>Text to be scraped</p></div>
</body>
```

How would I set up the `spider` in scrapy to just follow the links extracted from `index.html`?

I feel like the example from the tutorial does not help me much here:

from scrapy.spider import Spider

```
class IndexSpider(Spider):
    name = "index"
    allowed_domains = ["???"]
    start_urls = [
        "index.html"
    ]
```

Note: This is a simplified example. In the original example, all URLs are from the web and `index.html` contains a lot more links than just `1…4.html`.

The question is how to follow the extact links, which can be provided as a list, but will eventually stem from a xpath selector – select last column from table, but just every other row.

Comment: Basically the question is about how to parse the html file(s) saved locally?

Comment: @alecxe No, I just simplified the example. The question is how to follow certain links only. I can create a list for these, such as `["url1.com/…", "url2.com/…"]`. If unclear, I can extend the question…

Answer (score 2):

Use [CrawlSpider](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.contrib.spiders.CrawlSpider) and specify the rule for the [SmglLinkExtractor](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html#sgmllinkextractor):

```
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "mydomain"
    allowed_domains = ["www.mydomain"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.mydomain/index.html",]

    rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('\d+.html$', ),), callback="parse_items", follow=True), )

    def parse_items(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        # get the data
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this, it looks very promising to me…